# Upload table without duplicating rows

Tags: mysql

My table doesn't have a primary key.

I have to upload a bunch of data every month from a report.
How can I avoid inserting duplicates?
How can I find duplicates I've already created and resolve them?

This is my insert query:

```
INSERT INTO o1 
SELECT `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a01 a`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a01 b`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a02, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a03, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a11, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a12 a`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a12 b`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a12 c`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a21, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a22, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a23, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a24, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a25, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a31 a`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a31 b`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a32, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a33 a`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a33 b`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a33 c`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a34, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a41, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a42, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a43, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a51, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a52, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.a53, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a54 a`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a54 b`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a54 c`, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.b11, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.b12, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.b13, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.b14, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.b15, 
       `operazioni tipo info 1`.`a disp 1` 
FROM   `operazioni tipo info 1` 
WHERE  `operazioni tipo info 1`.a02 = 1 
       AND `operazioni tipo info 1`.a52 = 10 
        OR `operazioni tipo info 1`.a52 = 11 
        OR `operazioni tipo info 1`.a52 = 12 
        OR `operazioni tipo info 1`.a52 = 13
```

Comment: Try adding a unique constraint (or a PK) with `ALTER INGNORE`, it should delete the duplicates instead of throwing an error.

Comment: Just add that primary key. If need be, across all columns, but have one nonetheless.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the query you use for uploading data.

Comment: Show create table 01;

Comment: Hello everybody and thank you for your help; the problems was easier to solve than expected. In fact, it was enough to define a primary key (luckily, a column is fit for that). Now the upload of duplicated rows is not possible.This is the output error "[Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry '20121217000000000100' for key 'PRIMARY'"